# how to make two pivot format for two column

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

i have table like that

```
id | name  | date 1     | amount 1| date 2     | amount 2
---------------------------------------------------
1  | xxxx  | 01-02-2019 | 2000    | 02-04-2019 | 3500
2  | yyyy  | 01-04-2019 | 5000    | 01-06-2019 | 6800
```

i can make pivot only for one column , i use this code

```
TRANSFORM Sum(tbl1.[amount1]) AS SumOfamount1
SELECT tbl1.[fname], Sum(tbl1.[amount1]) AS [Total Of amount1]
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY tbl1.[fname]
PIVOT Format([date1],"mmm") In 
("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
```

this code okay for date1 and amount 1 
is it allow to make also for date2 and amount 2?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a subquery:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(t.[amont1]) AS SumOfamont1
SELECT t.[fname],
       Sum(t.[amount1]) AS [Total Of amount1]
FROM (SELECT date1, amont1, fname
      FROM tbl1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT date2, amont2, fname
      FROM tbl1
     ) t      
GROUP BY t.[fname]
PIVOT Format([date1], "mmm") In ("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May","Jun", "Jul", "Aug","Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
```

If this doesn't work, you might need to use a view for the `union all`.

Comment: thanks but i want to make pivot format for [date2] also with [date1]